# URL Provider- Websphere-Not able to read property file through java

Tags: java, url, provider

I am trying to configure URL provider on Webspehere. I am following the stepsprovided at the IBM Website:

1) Configure URL provider in websphere admin 
2) Updated web.xml 
3) Updated ibm-web-bnd.xm
4) Read the URL provider that was set in step 1
5) load the properties file

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_botzum/0502_botzum.html

I am getting an error while reading the URL provider through java code.

Following is the code snippet:

```
import java.net.URL
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import javax.naming.Context
import javax.naming.Intialcontext
import javax.naming.NamingException

 public class Test
 {
   public static void main ()
   {
     try
     {
       Context ctx = new IntialContext();
       String propertyFile = (String)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/url/TestProjectWSURL");
       URL url = new URL(propertyFile);
       System.out.println(url.getPath());
     }
     catch (NamingException e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
     catch (NamingException e)
     {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the stack trace is unavailable, my guess is that you are getting a class cast exception based on the below code

```
String propertyFile = (String)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/url/TestProjectWSURL");
```

You should cast it to URL instead of String. Below is the right way to do it (from the link you have provided)

```
InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();

URL url = (java.net.URL) initCtx.lookup(jndi);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem was with JNDI context. I have used the correct context after dumping the same using dumpNameSpace on Websphere. Thanks for your help.